# How can I migrate ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) from .Net 5 to .Net 6?

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to enable authentication to my own web api using Azure Active Directory B2C, and following the steps that the official documentations gives us I nees to use this code in my `startup.cs`, but it is for .Net 5 and I really don't know how to migrate it to .Net 6. Can you help me?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Adds Microsoft Identity platform (Azure AD B2C) support to protect this Api
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);

        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
    },
    options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });
    // End of the Microsoft Identity platform block    

    services.AddControllers();
}
```

My `Program.cs`:

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: What makes you think you need to change it?

Comment: What does your Program.cs file currently look like?

Comment: Wouldn't it be as easy as switching from `services` to `builder.Services`, and `Configuration` to `builder.Configuration`?

Comment: Not change it, my project is .Net 6 and never used Azure before, so I started reading the docs and they are for .Net 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference you are seeing is due to the ["top-level statements" feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements), and not necessarily to .NET5 vs .NET6.

To add the needed code, you can rely on your `builder` object, which provides you access to the services and configuration.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// Adds Microsoft Identity platform (Azure AD B2C) support to protect this Api
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);

        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
    },
    options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });
    // End of the Microsoft Identity platform block

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Thank you! I will check the link you provided me!